# Паттерн Singleton на Java

Tags: java, singleton, шаблоны-проектирования

Была дана задача:

```
/**
 * Создайте класс окружности Circle на координатной плоскости
 * Инициализация - радиус.
 * Он должен уметь:
 * 1) Предоставлять площадь круга, ограниченного этой окружностью.
 * 2) Изменять положение центра окружности.
 * 3) Отвечать на вопрос, есть ли пересечения хотя бы в 1 точке с другой окружностью.
 * 4) Вычислять расстояние до другой окружности(расстояние между их центрами).
 */
public class Circle {
    final double INITIAL_RADIUS = 0.0D;
    final double INITIAL_xCoordinate = 0.0D;
    final double INITIAL_yCoordinate = 0.0D;

    private double radius;
    private double xCoordinate;
    private double yCoordinate;

    public Circle() {
        this.radius = INITIAL_RADIUS;
        this.xCoordinate = INITIAL_xCoordinate;
        this.yCoordinate = INITIAL_yCoordinate;
    }

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.xCoordinate = INITIAL_xCoordinate;
        this.yCoordinate = INITIAL_yCoordinate;
    }

    public double squareOfCircle() {
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
    }

    public void setCenterOfCircle(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate) {
        this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
        this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
    }

    public double distanceBetweenCenter(Circle circle) {
        double x = Math.abs(circle.xCoordinate - this.xCoordinate);
        double y = Math.abs(circle.yCoordinate - this.yCoordinate);

        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    public boolean isIntersect(Circle circle) {
        return distanceBetweenCenter(circle) <= (circle.getRadius() + this.radius);
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }


}
```

Думаю сделал в ней все не так уж и плохо. Но вот вторую почему-то не получается понять, с паттернами раньше не работал) Прошу вашей помощи, все ли я правильно сделал ?

```
/**
 * 4. Написать синглтон для Circle.
 * Синглтон(одиночка) - некая схема, которая гарантирует,
 * что в программе будет объект некоторого класса в единственном экземпляре.
 * Подумать, как подправить класс из предыдущего задания, чтобы такая схема имела место.
 */

public class Circle {
    private static Circle circle;

    private double radius;
    private double xCoordinate;
    private double yCoordinate;

    private Circle(double radius, double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
        this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    }


    public static Circle getInstance(double radius, double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate) {
        if (circle == null) {
            circle = new Circle(radius, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        }
        return circle;
    }


    public double squareOfCircle() {
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
    }


}
```

Буду рад любой помощи :)

PS: 
поправил метод :

```
public static synchronized Circle getInstance(double radius, double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate) {
    if (circle == null) {
        circle = new Circle(radius, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
    }
    return circle;
}
```

Comment: вы практически правильно реализовали синглетон, только добавьте для метода getInstance(...) модификатор synchronized, т.к. иначе при обращении из нескольких потоков могут быть накладки

Comment: @Z.John  Спасибо, поправил

Comment: следующий шаг синглтон с [Double-checked_locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)